# Нужно ли второе тире в данном случае

Tags: приложение

> Важнейшее право человека и гражданина  - свобода самовыражения ()
> заключается в обязанности уважать чужое достоинство.

Нужно ли второе тире? Прав же много, а свобода самовыражения - это частность.
Не понимаю, как работает это правило:

> если приложение выражает более конкретное значение, а предшествующее
> определяемое слово имеет общее или образное значение: На совещании
> министров иностранных дел стран —  членов Организации американских
> государств выступил министр иностранных дел Кубы (газ.); При летели
> сюда первые ласточки —  наши спортсмены  для участия в парусных
> гонках; Высшая награда Французского института океанографии за
> выдающиеся океанографические работы  — медаль в память Альберта I
> принца Монакского  присуждена видному учёному Л. А. Зенькевичу

Применяется ли вообще это правило на письме?

Comment: Важнейшее право заключается в обязанности? Обычно права противопоставлены обязанностям.

Comment: Цитата (та, что ниже) никак не относится к делу. Ваша фраза напичкана понятиями под завязку, и от некоторых надо избавиться: *Важнейшее право каждого — право на самовыражение, ограниченное  осознанным уважением достоинства другого*.

Comment: Важнейшее право человека и гражданина – свобода самовыражения //предполагает  обязанность уважать чужое достоинство.

Comment: Зачем искажаете фразу? Вопрос про знак.

Comment: Татьяна Алексеевна, не имеет смысла говорить о знаке, если фраза (предложение) звучит и выглядит не лучшим образом. // просто чудовищно, извините.

Comment: Татьяна Алексеевна, не обижайтесь, пожалуйста, за критику в ваш адрес под принятым ответом. Мы все учимся друг у друга, и надо прислушиваться к чужому мнению. Вот на данный момент вы задали 63 вопроса, получили 94 ответа, а голосов отдали всего 36 (может, даже не все они за ответы именно на ваши вопросы). Почему бы не отметить участников хотя бы за внимание, время и труд? Тем более что многие их ответы содержат полезную информацию и в конечном итоге помогают найти правильное решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. Не нужно. Именно это правило здесь и работает.

Comment: Из Сети:  "Свобода самовыражения, или как абсолютная дозволенность под прикрытием либеральных ценностей и толерантности привела к тотальной дебилизации современной молодёжи".  Так это важнейшее право человека и гражданина или абсолютная дозволенность?  Такие разные мнения..

Comment: Спасибо вам за адекватный ответ.

Comment: А где обоснование решения? Согласиться с вами - это значит адекватно ответить? Тогда я тоже буду так отвечать: "Да, конечно, правильно говорите".  Другие участники вам говорят: предложение некорректно по стилю и смыслу, но это вас не интересует.

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна, вы просто хотите слышать (видеть) то, что хотите услышать (увидеть). Это давно видно по вашим вопросам. Чем этот ответ подкреплён? В чём и чему он адекватен? И почему вы тогда не ставите плюс (стрелочку) на полезные и адекватные ответы?

Comment: Меня устраивает принятый ответ, иначе я бы его не приняла. На этом закончу с вами диалог.

Comment: Уже какой ответ так принимается. Вот стихотворение обсуждали: я говорю перечислительная интонация, запятая на запятой,  в оригинале не так. Но вы принимает ответ по вашему мнению.

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна Зачем вы задаёте вопрос, если хотите получить только "да, вы правы"? Так стрелочку вверх за этот "устраиваемый" ответ почему не ставите?

Comment: Я поставила. Это вы ведете неспортивную борьбу и ставите минусы.

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна Какие такие минусы? О чём вы?

Comment: Если вам не нравятся мои вопросы и принимаемые мной ответы. То можете просто не игнорировать их и все.

Comment: Вы не хотите разобраться. Вы хотите услышать подтверждение своего мнения.

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна Хорошо, я так и делаю уже давно. А сейчас просто накипело!  // "То можете просто **не** игнорировать их"* Будьте внимательнее в своих формулировках.

Comment: Это ваше право.

Comment: Диалог:  –Не понимаю, как работает это правило... –  Именно это правило здесь и работает. – Спасибо вам за адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Sharon Да, смешно, парадокс на парадоксе едет и парадоксом погоняет!

Answer (score 3):

**1. О правиле как оно есть**

```
      Применяется ли вообще это правило на письме?
```

Правило действительно **интересное** и заслуживает внимания. Оно основано на правильном понимании **семантики предложения.** Там четко говорится:  Одно тире ставится, "если приложение выражает более **конкретное** значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет **общее или образное** значение.

Но предложение составлено **некорректно по смыслу.** Может ли важнейшее **право** заключаться **в обязанности**? Обычно права противопоставлены обязанностям. Текст: "Конституция РФ наряду с **правами** человека и гражданина закрепляет конституционные **обязанности**".

Вообще говоря, в таком тексте с большим количеством понятий и определений нужно ответственно использовать **каждое слово**, проверяя его значение. Поэтому применить правило **не получается**.

```
Нужно ли второе тире? Прав же много, а свобода самовыражения 
— это частность. Не понимаю, как работает это правило.
```

Но исправлять текст автор не хочет: "Зачем искажаете фразу? Вопрос про знак". В этом **ПАРАДОКС** ситуации.

**2. В чем особенность правила**

Так чем же интересно правило, почему мы убираем **одно тире**? Два тире ставится, если обособленное приложение содержит **дополнительную** информацию, а здесь информация  **основная.**

Может, обособить **запятыми?** Но такая конструкция останется вставочной. А разве есть **другие** варианты?

Вот другой вариант **и предлагается**. Мы как бы вообще не обособляем приложение (по структуре и интонации предложение остается **простым**), но при этом  приложение от определяемого слова **отделяется** тире (и произносительной паузой в устной речи).

**3. Как  правильно прочитать предложение**

Здесь тоже требуется внимание: *Прилетели сюда первые ласточки — **наши спортсмЕны** // для участия в парусных гОнка.*

В таком предложении **основная** пауза делается после приложения, а тире обозначает **произносительную** паузу.

Вот такое это ***удивительное правило***.

**4. Редактирование**

Предложенный мною вариант **с минимальной правкой** выглядел так:

*Важнейшее право человека и гражданина **– свобода самовыражения** // **предполагает** обязанность уважать чужое достоинство.*

**P. S. Дополнительный материал по теме**

**САМОВЫРАЖЕНИЕ**, -я; ср. Выражение себя, своей индивидуальности в какой-л. деятельности. С. личности. С. писателя.

**СВОБОДА,** -ы; ж. **6. чего или с инф.** Возможность **действовать** в какой-л. области без ограничений, запретов, беспрепятственно. С. торговли. С. передвижения. С. печати. С. собраний. С. творчества. С. морей (право..). С. слова и мысли (право иметь и выражать свои взгляды). С. совести (право на убеждения, на моральный выбор). С. мыслей, рассудка, духа (независимость, самостоятельность мыслей, духа)

[Свобода самовыражения или...](https://dzen.ru/a/XcBlFB6OPwCx5Dyk)

[Свобода самовыражения](https://dzen.ru/a/YgqPh_tXBgcNqXMZ)

Answer (score 2):

Ну да ладно. Все комменты прочла.

Без второго тире: свобода самовыражения заключается в обязанности уважать чужое достоинство.

Если ставим второе, "свобода самовыражения" легко изымается из предложения; получаем:

Важнейшее **право** человека и гражданина **заключается в обязанности** уважать чужое достоинство.

То есть то, что уже обсуждалось.

Мне кажется, что спасти текст можно только перестройкой:

Свобода самовыражения - важнейшее право человека и гражданина - заключается в обязанности уважать чужое достоинство.

Тогда два тире на месте. И осмысленность некая проявляется. Тяготеет к максиме:

*Твоя свобода заканчивается там, где начинается свобода другого.*